# s3 throttling stream uploading using AWS-Android-SDK?

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, stream, throttling

We had gone through the link for iOS-SDK.
http://aws.amazon.com/articles/0006282245644577

Is it possible in android to implement stream throttling like iOS?

If yes, how we are going to implement it? How to check whether it's working correctly?

Answer (score 1):

That is a very old article. It only applies to AWS SDK for iOS v1. The latest version is v2.3.2. Throttling is no longer supported in v2. As for the AWS SDK for Android, such feature has never been implemented. You probably need 3rd party app to achieve that.